# Powershell variables not written correctly

Tags: powershell

So in my Powershell script I have 2 variables getting multiplied by each other, but there is one problem, Powershell can't tell that I want to multiply the variables by each other. The script is below:

`$answer = $a*$equation`

The `$a` variable is `7`.
The `$equation` variable is `365*675/54`
So what I want the script to do is `7*365*675/54` and set the answer to the `$answer` variable.

When I debug the script it says that the problem is in the `* symbol`. Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 3):

I would use `Invoke-Expression` instead of running another PowerShell instance.

```
$answer = Invoke-Expression "$a*$equation"
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the behavior you want is for Powershell to interpret the variable `$equation` as a mathematical; expression and not a value.  In general this is not how variables work in powershell.  They represent values, not expressions.  Hence powershell sees this as a `string` and not a number.

This can be done though by spinning up another instance of powershell and asking it to interpret the string.  It will then return the result which you can store

```
$resolved = powershell $equation
$answer = $a * $resolved
```

Comment: Thanks! I needed this for the rest of my script to function correctly and I couldn't find any answers on Google.